# Hibernate delete entity OneToMany is not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am developing an application using SpringBoot and Hibernate.
The problem: When I delete de contained entity this action is not reflected in real time on the containing entity but it is reflecting in my database.
(I think that it is related with the context of hibernate or the cache of hibernate)

The Code is:

```
    public UserDto deleteMeetPhoto(User user, String photoID) {
    
    PhotoMeet photoAux = photoMeetDao.selectPhotoByIdAndUser(photoID, user.getId());
    photoMeetDao.deletePhoto(photoAux.getId(), user.getId());
    //Refreshing the user 
    user = userDao.findById(user.getId()).get();

    return new UserDto(user);
}
```

The User entity code:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = false, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE,
        CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private List<PhotoMeet> photos;
```

The PhotoMeet code:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH,
        CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

Answer (score 0):

*The issue you're facing might be related to Hibernate's first-level cache and second-level cache. When you delete an entity using Hibernate, the changes are not immediately reflected in the first-level cache or the in-memory representation of the associated entities.*

By default, your relationship is marked as lazy-loaded (fetch = FetchType.LAZY). This means that Hibernate will load the photos collection only when you access it explicitly. If you want changes to be reflected immediately, you can change the fetch strategy to FetchType.EAGER:

---

Ensure that your method is annotated with `@Transactional`. This will manage the transaction and session properly, and any changes made to the entities will be reflected when the transaction is committed:

```
@Transactional
public UserDto deleteMeetPhoto(User user, String photoID) {
    // Your delete logic here
}
```